# Pycharm does not resolve part of the package

Tags: python, pycharm, package

Straight to the point,

I installed python pptx, and PyCharm resolves part of it but not all of it.
Could you please help me how to fix it?

[image]

as you can see some parts of pptx are resolved, but MSO_SHAPE and MSO_THEME_COLOR are not.
the package is installed.
I used both (pip install pyhotn-pptx) and from the project interpretor.
I am using pyhotn 3.9 if it matters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to ignore it and run some code anyway? Does it work? If you didn't try then do, sometimes Pycharm does gives you imports error but then it works anyway

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot. I can't believe I missed 4 hours on that. You should write that as an answer, that may save someone else's time. Thanks again, that was it.

Comment: Yes I added, if was helpful marked it as accepted and vote up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this solved actually the issue, I report it an actual answer.

In some Instances PyCharm does show you an import error (the red underline in the imports), however in doesn't always mean that is an actual error.

So if you run in this issue do the following:

- Run the code anyway and see if it works, if it does you can ignore that error message.

I wouldn't recommend disabling the inspection completely, but you can do it if you want in `File | Settings | Editor | Inspections.`

[image]

- Try to use another IDLE or Terminal and see if the error persists.